# How to tell if your USB ports support USB 3.0?

Tags: usb

I'm a Ubuntu 10.04 user. What's the fastest way to tell if the two USB ports on my computer support USB 3.0? I'm not sure if they're 2.0 or 3.0, and I need to know. Thanks!

Comment: Manufactures have taken a liking to making 3.0 ports blue, can't be sure of always though.

Comment: Confirmed, mine is blue :)

Comment: My USB3.0 port is blue and has the extra pins - my USB2.0 only has the 4 pins, but is also blue

Answer (score 6):

First be sure that your motherboard SAYS "Supports USB 3.0"

Then you can for example go to the terminal and type `lsusb` and it will show the version of the usb.

Another can be `lshw` but it shows a lot of info

If you want super full info then do `sudo lsusb -v` this should give you whole information about all ports and anything connected to any usb port.

Answer (score 6):

Just look at the ports on the machine and if they are blue-ish then it is USB3.

Answer (score 4):

Look at a USB 2.0 port.

It has a black "tongue"

A USB 3.0 port has a blue one.